# Load single package at runtime

Tags: delphi

We're using the chromium browser component https://github.com/hgourvest/dcef3 in our application.  We recently updated this and today found out that it gives an access violation when running on Windows 2008 machines and older.

This AV happens as soon as you start the application.  The part where this component is used, is only a small part of the application.

I hoped a solution would be to load that package at runtime instead of design time, but the option to dynamically link runtime packages seems to be an all-or-nothing decising.  We want to keep all our other packages internally in the exe.

What would be a solution for this?  Is there a way of telling Delphi it should only load that package when needed?  That way the users running on Windows 2008 servers can continue to use the other parts of the application.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that runtime loading will solve your problem. Why don't you try to identify the problem before trying to solve it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan well since Chrome itself doesn't want to update on those machine I don't find it too strange that that component is giving AV's.  Previous version of the component worked fine but used an older chrome engine which doesn't fully support the web anymore for our purpose.

Comment: But I don't see why load time loading of packages is a way to avoid this AV. Do you have any evidence?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I see what you mean.  No no evidence yet.  We're continuing this on monday. When we compile the whole project without including the component unit in the uses, it starts fine.  As soon as we include it in using (even though that form doesn't seem to be loaded), it refuses to start.

Comment: If this code produces an AV at startup then surely it will do so whether the component is linked runtime or compile time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes but what if we only link it when we need it.  As said it's only a small part of the application.  That way people running on Windows 2008 can continue to use the other parts of the application.

Comment: If it were me I'd identify the problem. If you want to give up then do so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Since the Chrome browser itself is refusing to upgrade on those machines mentioning Chrome is no longer able to update their version on this OS, I have little hope on solving that part...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically load the packages like a DLL. You can't use RTTI, but you can load and execute procedures from the Package.

You can load a package with code like this:

```
H := LoadPackage('RESTAS.BPL');
```

And access methods with code like this:

```
@resta := GetProcAddress(H, 'Resta');
```

Similar to a DLL.
[Here you have a complete explanation](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/dlls-bpls-carga-dinamicaestatica-y-packages-en-runtime/) related with packages load (BPL's) and libraries (DLL's) in delphi, with different configuractions (with and without runtime packages). It's in spanish, but you can use automathic translation and see code and download samples.

Comment: Thanks, the Spanish project is helpful :)